# How to disable start up programs for only one user

Tags: user, msconfig

The title says it all. I got 2 accounts. How do I disable some programs with `msconfig` on that particular account but not on the other account?

Answer (score 1):

Download this free program https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx from Microsoft Technet. (if link fails, google "autoruns for windows")

Download to Desktop; 2x-click on autoruns.exe, allow it to scan the registry (status on bottom-left of screen)

Click on the user tab - you will see numerous user accounts - choose one and then click on the "logon" tab - un-check the boxes for those items you wish that particular user not to have run at logon; repeat for others

I hope this helps.